# QT Creator Error (no match for operator =)

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qdir, qstandardpaths

I'm receiving this error everytime I build my code. I'm using QT Creator 3.1, (5.2.1 build)

> error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'QStringList' and 'const char [2]')

Here is a snippet of code, hope it can help (the asterix line is where the error is highlighted)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Shutdown = false;

QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setApplicationName("aQtLow");

//Create default data paths if they don't exist
QDir Path;
**MainPath = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation) + "/" + a.applicationName() + "Data";**
Path.setPath(MainPath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate a QStringList with QStrings since

```
QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation)
```

returns a `QStringList`.

You would need to gt the element you wish to reuse, e.g. using the `.first()` method. You could write this:

> MainPath = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation).first() + "/" + a.applicationName() + "/Data";

Note that I just added a missing "/" between the application name and the "Data" because I think that would be more logical to use, but feel free to reject that edit if you wish.

But since you seem to be interested in the data directory location, I would suggest to use the dedicated enum from `QStandardPaths`:

or it would be even better to just use:

> QStandardPaths::DataLocation  9   Returns a directory location where persistent application data can be stored. QCoreApplication::organizationName and QCoreApplication::applicationName are appended to the directory location returned for GenericDataLocation.

You could write this then:

```
QDir Path(QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DataLocation).first());
```

In fact, if you wish to avoid the `.first()` call, you could probably use the [writableLocation()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation) method as follows:

```
QDir Path(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation));
```

=====================================================

Out of curiosity, this could also be an alternative:

> [QString QDir::homePath () [static]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#homePath)

or

> [QDir QDir::home () [static]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#home)

as follows:

```
QDir Path = QDir::home();
Path.cd(a.applicationName() + "Data");
```

or

```
QDir Path(QDir::homePath() + "/" + a.applicationName() + "/Data");
```

If that is not enough, there is even [one more alternative](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath):

```
QDir Path(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath + "/Data");
```

Comment: You're wonderful Laszlo, I will experiment today and let you know my results. Thank you for your wonderful intelligent response!

Answer (score 0):

QStandardPaths::standardLocations return QStringList. You should use QStringList::join or QStringList::at or use foreach. Mb you want to do something else but I don`t know what because variable MainPath so mysterious =)